# Floating divs top to bottom and then left to right in a fixed height container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to float DIVs vertically from top to bottom and from left to right in a fixed height container. [Vetically floating DIV arrange from up to down by rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316329/div-vetically-floating-div-arrange-from-up-to-down-by-rows) raises the same issue and a solution has been given in the cases where divs have the size height:width as 1:1. In my cases each div is a long rectangle and as expected the solution explained in the above post breaks.

I was able to find another solution using a new css property called flex columns.The below given style does the job but it wont work in older versions of webkit.

```
<style>
.container {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;

}
.area {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="area">area1</div>
    <div class="area">area2</div>
    <div class="area">area3</div>
    <div class="area">area4</div>
    <div class="area">area5</div>
    <div class="area">area6</div>
</div>
```

My planing result should be like this:

```
    ---------------------------->
    | -------- --------
    | |Area 1| |Area 5|
    | -------- --------
    | -------- --------
max | |Area 2| |Area 6|
500 | -------- --------
 px | --------
    | |Area 3|   etc..
    | --------
    | --------             /\
    | |Area 4|   etc....... |
    | --------   
    --------------------------->
```

The number of items in the list is arbitrary. As the number of items increases it should grow sideways.

My questions is: Can we have any solution which works in older versions of webkit. I DONT need a solution which works across all browser. My product is specific to webkit.

Or it will be really helpful if someone can give pointers on the modifications to be made for the solution mentioned in the duplicate post I have mentioned.

Comment: `id` should be unique

Comment: possible duplicate of [css flexbox break parent by screen width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17290107/css-flexbox-break-parent-by-screen-width)

Comment: @cimmanon I am not sure if this can be modified to suit my need. In the post the ordering seems to be from left to right and then top to bottom. What I need is the reverse case. Also the reason I am looking for another solution is that display:flex wont work with Jelly Bean Android's webkit.

Comment: @Arun Look at the second part of the answer.

Comment: @cimmanon Will it be possible to handle the case when there is a large number of items in the list? The expected behaviour is that I should have a scrolling region with the list growing sideways. With columns it seems the list will grow downwards.

Comment: @cimmanon I tried a few combinations but it was just not working. http://jsfiddle.net/Cu8m4/ Can you give it a look?

Comment: I tried a few combinations but it was just not working. http://jsfiddle.net/arbabu/8Ra4x/1/ Can you give it a look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should give you what you're looking for.

```css
.container {
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:column wrap;
    max-height:500px;
    background:#ccc;
}
.area {
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background:#444;
    margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="area">area1</div>
    <div class="area">area2</div>
    <div class="area">area3</div>
    <div class="area">area4</div>
    <div class="area">area5</div>
    <div class="area">area6</div>
</div>
```

I added the color so I could see what I was working with.